# Firebase Analytics data is abnormal

Tags: android, ios

Today we checked the data. Since August 23, the usage time and the number of users have dropped by nearly 100%. Our internal data shows no abnormal fluctuations, and there has been no version release for a while. Is there something wrong with Firebase Speech Service?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxTTA.png)

I have checked some recent notifications from Firebase, but no relevant exceptions have been notified, and I hope to restore the data to normal.

Comment: #Firebase Analytics Dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the firebase license period is expired.

Comment: Thanks. Not expired, It is a mechanism for updating Firebase data. New data does not take effect immediately and is updated 1-2 days later.